# Android MediaPlayer default timeout

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-networking, androidhttpclient

Does anybody know, what is the default timeout for the MediaPlayer class of Android, when using a HTTP URL as source? So far as I searched, it is not possible to set this timeout (unlike in HttpURLConnection), and only get information about it by implementing the MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener interface, but does anyone what is the default timeout after which it send a call to this method (MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener.onError()) (and also with which "what" and "extra" pre-API Level 17)?

Comment: I guess I answered your question in similar post :  http://stackoverflow.com/a/29132444/2899437